# Iotのデータに関するSQLの作成について

Tags: sql, postgresql

### 仮定

施設に停留している機器を記録するシステムがある。(各施設での監視記録であるため機体移動中の記録はない)
表Aにはどの施設にどの機体が停留しているか機体名、施設名、記録時刻が記載さている。
機体が施設Aから施設Bに移動した際のFromとToの(施設名, 時刻)の一覧を表Bとする。

### 質問

このとき表Bを作成するSQL(PostgreSQL 10.4)をご教示ください。

表Aと表Bの例を用意いたしました。下表Bは手動で作成いたしました。実際の表Aは100万行以上の行を持っています。
表A

```
  No  機体名  施設名  時刻    
  --  ------  ------  --------
   1  機体A   市役所  13:18:56
   2  機体B   裁判所  13:19:19
   3  機体C   警察署  13:19:25
   4  機体A   保健所  14:08:18
   5  機体B   裁判所  14:18:40
   6  機体A   気象台  14:20:10
   7  機体C   警察署  14:28:45
   8  機体A   気象台  14:30:11
   9  機体C   官公署  14:36:48
  10  機体C   官公署  14:38:47
  11  機体C   官公署  14:40:47
  12  機体A   高校    14:46:19
  13  機体C   博物館  14:50:42
  14  機体C   博物館  14:52:42
  15  機体B   神社    14:54:41
  16  機体C   博物館  14:54:43
  17  機体C   博物館  14:56:40
  18  機体C   博物館  14:58:40
  19  機体C   神社    15:06:40
  20  機体C   神社    15:08:38
  21  機体B   工場    15:10:43
  22  機体C   官公署  15:14:48
  23  機体B   消防署  15:18:41
  24  機体B   消防署  15:20:40
  25  機体B   消防署  15:22:40
  26  機体B   神社    15:28:38
  27  機体A   高校    15:36:18
  28  機体A   高校    15:38:17
  29  機体B   神社    15:48:39
  30  機体C   官公署  15:48:48
  31  機体A   交番    15:50:16
  32  機体C   神社    15:56:38
  33  機体C   郵便局  16:02:42
  34  機体B   小中校  16:16:42
  35  機体C   郵便局  16:16:42
  36  機体A   交番    16:18:16
  37  機体B   小中校  16:18:42
  38  機体C   郵便局  16:18:42
```

表B

```
  No  機体名  施設名From  時刻From     施設名To   時刻To   
  --  ------  -------     -----------  --------   --------
   1  機体A   市役所      13:18:56     保健所     14:08:18
   2  機体A   保健所      14:08:18     気象台     14:20:10
   3  機体C   警察署      14:28:45     官公署     14:36:48
   4  機体A   気象台      14:30:11     高校       14:46:19
   5  機体C   官公署      14:40:47     博物館     14:50:42
   6  機体B   裁判所      14:18:40     神社       14:54:41
   7  機体C   博物館      14:58:40     神社       15:06:40
   8  機体B   神社        14:54:41     工場       15:10:43
   9  機体C   神社        15:08:38     官公署     15:14:48
  10  機体B   工場        15:10:43     消防署     15:18:41
  11  機体B   消防署      15:22:40     神社       15:28:38
  12  機体A   高校        15:38:17     交番       15:50:16
  13  機体C   官公署      15:48:48     神社       15:56:38
  14  機体C   神社        15:56:38     郵便局     16:02:42
  15  機体B   神社        15:48:39     小中校     16:16:42
```

Answer (score 1):

ウィンドウ関数のleadを用いることで、実現可能です。

テーブル

```
CREATE TABLE events
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    machine text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    place text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "time" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT events_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

データ

```
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (1,'機体A','市役所','13:18:56');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (2,'機体B','裁判所','13:19:19');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (3,'機体C','警察署','13:19:25');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (4,'機体A','保健所','14:08:18');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (5,'機体B','裁判所','14:18:40');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (6,'機体A','気象台','14:20:10');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (7,'機体C','警察署','14:28:45');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (8,'機体A','気象台','14:30:11');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (9,'機体C','官公署','14:36:48');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (10,'機体C','官公署','14:38:47');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (11,'機体C','官公署','14:40:47');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (12,'機体A','高校','14:46:19');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (13,'機体C','博物館','14:50:42');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (14,'機体C','博物館','14:52:42');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (15,'機体B','神社','14:54:41');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (16,'機体C','博物館','14:54:43');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (17,'機体C','博物館','14:56:40');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (18,'機体C','博物館','14:58:40');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (19,'機体C','神社','15:06:40');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (20,'機体C','神社','15:08:38');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (21,'機体B','工場','15:10:43');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (22,'機体C','官公署','15:14:48');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (23,'機体B','消防署','15:18:41');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (24,'機体B','消防署','15:20:40');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (25,'機体B','消防署','15:22:40');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (26,'機体B','神社','15:28:38');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (27,'機体A','高校','15:36:18');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (28,'機体A','高校','15:38:17');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (29,'機体B','神社','15:48:39');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (30,'機体C','官公署','15:48:48');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (31,'機体A','交番','15:50:16');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (32,'機体C','神社','15:56:38');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (33,'機体C','郵便局','16:02:42');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (34,'機体B','小中校','16:16:42');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (35,'機体C','郵便局','16:16:42');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (36,'機体A','交番','16:18:16');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (37,'機体B','小中校','16:18:42');
INSERT INTO "events" ("id","machine","place","time") VALUES (38,'機体C','郵便局','16:18:42');
```

クエリ

```
select * from (
  select machine, place as from_place, time as from_time, lead(place) over w as to_place, lead(time) over w as to_time
  from events
  window w as (partition by machine order by time)
) as with_lead
where to_place <> from_place
order by to_time;
```

結果

```
 machine | from_place | from_time | to_place | to_time
---------+------------+-----------+----------+----------
 機体A   | 市役所     | 13:18:56  | 保健所   | 14:08:18
 機体A   | 保健所     | 14:08:18  | 気象台   | 14:20:10
 機体C   | 警察署     | 14:28:45  | 官公署   | 14:36:48
 機体A   | 気象台     | 14:30:11  | 高校     | 14:46:19
 機体C   | 官公署     | 14:40:47  | 博物館   | 14:50:42
 機体B   | 裁判所     | 14:18:40  | 神社     | 14:54:41
 機体C   | 博物館     | 14:58:40  | 神社     | 15:06:40
 機体B   | 神社       | 14:54:41  | 工場     | 15:10:43
 機体C   | 神社       | 15:08:38  | 官公署   | 15:14:48
 機体B   | 工場       | 15:10:43  | 消防署   | 15:18:41
 機体B   | 消防署     | 15:22:40  | 神社     | 15:28:38
 機体A   | 高校       | 15:38:17  | 交番     | 15:50:16
 機体C   | 官公署     | 15:48:48  | 神社     | 15:56:38
 機体C   | 神社       | 15:56:38  | 郵便局   | 16:02:42
 機体B   | 神社       | 15:48:39  | 小中校   | 16:16:42
(15 rows)
```

#### ちなみに

上記クエリは、 MySQL(>=8.0) でも有効だったりします。(同じようなテーブル定義だった場合)

Comment: こちらでも以下のSQLで自己解決できました。
よろしければ効率性の観点で@Yuki Inoue♦さまのSQLとの相違点をご教示いただければ幸いです。
```
select row_number() over(order by e1.time) as id,
       e1.machine as machine,
       e2.place as place_from,
       e2.time as time_from,
       e1.place as place_to,
       e1.time as time_to
  from events e1, events e2
 where e1.machine = e2.machine
   and e1.place <> e2.place
   and e2.time = (select max(time)
                    from events e3
                   where e1.machine = e3.machine
                     and e1.time > e3.time);
```

Comment: 効率性、となると元の質問から外れてくるので、別途新しい質問として分けたほうが良さそうです。

Comment: 承知しました。

ちなみに主キーインデックスのみ貼った状態のexplainで@Yuki Inoue♦さんのSQLのほうが40,000倍コストが低かったです。
@Yuki Inoue♦さん改めてご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

(返答と同様です)こちらでも以下のSQLで自己解決できました。  
よろしければ効率性の観点で@Yuki Inoue♦さまのSQLとの相違点をご教示いただければ幸いです。

```
select row_number() over(order by e1.time) as id,
       e1.machine as machine,
       e2.place as place_from,
       e2.time as time_from,
       e1.place as place_to,
       e1.time as time_to
  from events e1, events e2
 where e1.machine = e2.machine
   and e1.place <> e2.place
   and e2.time = (select max(time)
                    from events e3
                   where e1.machine = e3.machine
                     and e1.time > e3.time);
```